# how to remove \t from result

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have parsed a web page and written all the links into a csv file; when I try to read these links from the csv I am getting this:

`[['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tI\tn\ts\tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t8\t5\t8\t7\t7\t8\t0\t1\t1'],
['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tP\tr\ti\tm\te\t-\tI\tn\ts\tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t6\t7\t6\t8\t8\t2\t0\t1\t1']]`

`\t` is coming after each and every letter ,i have tried this to remove `\t` from the result but no luck
Here is my code

```
out=open("categories.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
new_data=[[row[1]] for row in data]
new_data = new_data.strip('\t\n\r')
print new_data
```

This is giving an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: You have tabs *between every individual character*; how did you write this to begin with? `csv.writerow('single url string')`?

Comment: Need to learn basic programming first: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function for easy substition in strings:

```
import re
string = "[['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tI\tn\ts \tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t8\t5\t8\t7\t7\t8\t0\t1\t1'], ['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tP\tr\ti\tm\te\t-\tI\tn\ts\tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t6\t7\t6\t8\t8\t2\t0\t1\t1']]"

new_string = re.sub(r'\t', '', string)

print new_string
```

=======  OUTPUT:

```
[['http://www.amazon.com/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=2858778011'], ['http://www.amazon.com/Prime-Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=2676882011']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the strip method only remove blank characters from both end of string.
Try the below approach:

```
out=open("categories.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
new_data=[[''.join(row[0].strip().split('\t'))] for row in data]
print new_data
```

Answer (score 0):

as a kludge solution:

```
x = [['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tI\tn\ts\tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t8\t5\t8\t7\t7\t8\t0\t1\t1'],['\th\tt\tt\tp\t:\t/\t/\tw\tw\tw\t.\ta\tm\ta\tz\to\tn\t.\tc\to\tm\t/\tP\tr\ti\tm\te\t-\tI\tn\ts\tt\ta\tn\tt\t-\tV\ti\td\te\to\t/\tb\t?\ti\te\t=\tU\tT\tF\t8\t&\tn\to\td\te\t=\t2\t6\t7\t6\t8\t8\t2\t0\t1\t1']]

for y in x:
   for z in y:
       print("".join(z.split('\t')))
```

Returns:

```
> http://www.amazon.com/Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=2858778011
> http://www.amazon.com/Prime-Instant-Video/b?ie=UTF8&node=2676882011
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to index to the string then do a simple replace

```
string = [[...],[...]...]

lst = []
for ylst in string:
    for ln in ylst:
        lst.append(ln.replace('\t',''))
```

lst will contain each line without the '\t's